# Is there a way to generate all the routes required for user authentication using Passport?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-passport

I am working in a project with laravel 5.8.28 using Passport. I would like to use a helper class that generates and maps all the routes required for user authentication, using passport.

Like  `Auth::routes()` but with passport.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your `AuthServiceProvider` boot method you can add this:

```
Passport::routes();

// don't forget the import on the top:
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
```

Please read [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#installation) for more.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer didn't take me directly to the solution but actually helped me to find it. I just nedeed to modify the /vendor/framework......./routing file, so in my routes.php I just use auth::routes(). And of course adding what you told me. Thank you again

Comment: And what is the correct solution to your question? I would love to know.

Comment: Then you can consider accepting the answer. And please don't edit framework files directly because that's not a solution at all. When you will need to upgrade you will face issues.